# can I deploy my wsp using central admin and avoid login to development server

Tags: deployment, sharepoint-2010, wsp

I need on clarification that I have a development server where according to the policy I shouldn't login and run the commands.

So, is there any way that I can deploy my solution using central admin just like as we did through power shell commands.

I search before, but I couldn't get the satisfactory answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can setup powershell to run remotely and then use powershell commands to deploy the wsp.
Check this link on enabling powershell to run remotely [Configure Remote PowerShell in SharePoint 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varun_malhotra/archive/2010/06/10/configure-power-shell-for-remote-use-of-sp-2010.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you're deploying new wsp, you can run Powershell command "Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath ". If it's an existing wsp, you should retract the existing wsp first before adding the updated wsp. You can check if the wsp either deployed or not in the Central Admin > System Settings > Manage Farm solution. You can also deploy the SP Solution(once added) in Central admin. After deploying it, make sure to restart the Timer Service. [Here's](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262995%28v=office.14%29.aspx) how you can deploy the wsp using powershell.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of solution are you deploying? Is it a farm or sandboxed solution? You can deploy your solutiions via VS2010 without having to login to the server. Or are you referring to items that needs to be deployed via GAC?

Comment: but what about the iisrest because when VS-2010 deploy on that server does it requires some special rights on remote machine to deploy the wsp?

Comment: you can check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee231585(v=vs.100).aspx for more information :)